# align with symbols other than equality

Tags: align, amsmath

I have to represent "equations" with both equalities and transitions. I tried using align but the fact that the transition symbol is larger than the equality symbol makes it look weird.

```
\begin{align}a &= \sum_k^l k\\
&\triangleright^+ \sum_k^l k\end{align}
```

Is there some simple way to fix that? I could use an array instead but then the vertical space between two lines is a bit too small, and I have to add `\displaystyle` everywhere...

```
\[\begin{array}{rll}
a & = & \displaystyle\sum_k^l k\\
&\triangleright^+ &\displaystyle\sum_k^l k
\end{array}\]
```

Is there some simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `alignat` is for:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Using align:
\begin{align}
a &= \sum_k^l k\\
&\triangleright^+ \sum_k^l k
\end{align}

Using alignat:
\begin{alignat}{2}
&a &=& \sum_k^l k\\
&&\triangleright^+& \sum_k^l k
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make an equals sign as wide as the transition symbol.

By the way, `\triangleright` is not a relation symbol, so it's better to make it into one, with a new command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}

\newcommand{\teq}{\mathrel{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\transition$}]{=}}}
\newcommand{\transition}{\mathrel{\triangleright^+}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &\teq        \sum_k^l k\\
  &\transition \sum_k^l k
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage is also that you can change your mind about the appearance of the symbol. For instance, if you modify the definition into

```
\newcommand{\transition}{\mathrel{\triangleright^{\!+}}}
```

the output, without modifying the document's body, would become

[image]